# Switching To ConTeXt Minimals: Missing Last Step for MacTeX 2010

Tags: installing, context

While digging around in my texmf-dist/doc/context/document/general/manuals directory, as I'm want to do on a Sunday, I found the "tiptrick" PDF, which helpfully suggests that I can install the ConTeXt minimals by doing the following:

```
 cd ..../tex/texmf-local
   wget http://www.pragma-ade.com/context/current/cont-tmf.zip
   unzip cont-tmf.zip
   texexec --make --alone --all
```

I do this in my $HOMETEXMF directory. The trouble is, I get the following head and tail when I run it from TextMate:

```
MTXrun | warning: no format found, forcing remake (commandline driven)
MTXrun | fileio: loading configuration file '/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmfcnf.lua'
```

...

```
'/Users/andrew/Library/texlive/2010/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/e9159e878e989105b2ef2d27fad97515/trees/1240e363db2f4c53de58379d2b0c6f6b.luc'
...andrew/src/texmf/scripts/context/lua/mtx-context.lua:985: attempt to call upvalue 'make_mkiv_format' (a nil value)
```

The interweb has suggested a few things. `minstall.pdf` as a document of interest... not found on my computer anywhere...

```
source /opt/context-minimals/setuptex
```

Sounded promising, but nothing like that is in my install anywhere, except a Windows batch file called `setuptex.bat` and not in my directory.

I tried `texexec --make --all`, if that's supposed to help. So, using texexec seems to work now, but only kinda-sort-of. Getting fonts to work, either with `simplefonts` (`Un
defined control sequence. l.139 \doifolderversionelse`) or by using:

```
\usetypescriptfile[type-mac]
\usetypescript[gillsans]
\setupbodyfont[Gill Sans,12pt]
```

So, why is `mtxrun` now broken? Which should I be using, `texexec` or `mtxrun`? Why is `simplefonts` broken and what really is the best method for font selection, given that I want to be able to put the fonts into my tds tree and have them portable between multiple computers that are building these documents, which are updated from source control. (I assign my `$HOMETEXMF` directory to `src/texmf` on every computer and plan on updating ConTeXt and related packages within this).

I admit to not fully understanding everything about this system, and I appologize for asking things that are probably explained somewhere else. I swear I've done my share of searching for the answer elsewhere. :) I'd be happy to RTFM, if I could find one that had the relevant information! :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are following a bit outdated installation instruction, check ConTeXt wiki for more [up to date one](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Minimals#Detailed_information_on_installation_and_use_on_Unix-like_platforms_.28Linux.2FMacOS_X.2FFreeBSD.2FSolaris.29).

Also, ConTeXt minimals is a standalone TeX distribution, so you can't install it inside TeXLive, but alongside it. If all you want is to update ConTeXt in TeXLive, then check [tlcontib repository](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I imagine that this all should have been obvious to me, but alas, it was not. Once I know what I'm doing and have it all working, I'm going to start contributing to the documentation effort. :)